# Compare Names and DOB in two Excel sheets and return the value in a third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Valued programmers, I hope you can help me modify the VBA code below so it works properly.
I have an Excel workbook that consists of two worksheets.
Worksheet "Data" contains Names (Column A), DOB (Column B) and Numbers (Column C) and can go up to around 300k rows.
Worksheet "Search" contains Names(Column A) and DOB (Column B)
I want to compare sheet "Search" with sheet "Data" and return the value from Column "Number" to Column C of the "Search" tab if the DOB is completely identical and if at least part of the name is identical. One of the sheets can for instance have only capitals or an insertion or maiden name added to the name, while in the other sheet this information might be missing.
I tried to alter a code I found online, but am still a newbie at VBA and it already gives me an error at the title. Can't seem to find out what I did wrong (placed it in a module).
Hope to get some usefull tips.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Search()

        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim LastrowS1 As Long, LastrowS2 As Long
        Dim NameS1 As String, DOBS1 As String, NameS2 As String, DOBS2 As String
        Dim NumberS1 As Number

        LastrowS1 = Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastrowS2 = Search.Cells(Search.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastrowS1
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
                NameS1 = .Range("A" & i).Value
                DOBS1 = .Range("B" & i).Value
                NumberS1 = .Range("C" & i).Value
            End With
                For j = 2 To LastrowS2
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Search")
                        NameS2 = .Range("A" & j).Value
                        DOBS2 = .Range("B" & j).Value
                    End With

                    If NameS1 = NameS2 And DOBS1 = DOBS2 Then
                        Search.Range("C" & j).Value = NumberS1
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next j

            Next i

    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative answer** (also because doing it in formulae is fun):

I would actually try to avoid VBA for this one. I would sort "data" by DOB, then add a helper column "MATCHING DOBs" in D2 downwards like so `=IF(B3=B2,D3,ROW())`.
This will keep track of the number of DOBs that are the same.

Now a MATCH on DOB will return the index to the first matching DOB, and the corresponding value in row D indicates the index for the last matching DOB. The full range of names for those matching DOBs will then be

```
=INDEX(Data!$A:$A,MATCH(B2,Data!$B:$B,0)):INDEX(Data!$A:$A,INDEX(Data!$D:$D,MATCH(B2,Data!$B:$B,0)))               ...can be optimised a bit with LET in office 365 to only calculate MATCH(...) once
```

Now enter the following as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(*range above*,A2)), 0)           ...array formula CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
```

It will return the index into *range above* where the "short name" in data occurs somewhere in A2 of the SEARCH sheet.

The final number in C column for the matching name and DOB will be

```
=INDEX(Data!$C:$C, MATCH(B2,Data!$B:$B,0) + *match index above* - 1)
```

or all-in-one (remember CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER):

```
=INDEX(Data!$C:$C, MATCH(B2,Data!$B:$B,0) + MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Data!$A:$A,MATCH(B2,Data!$B:$B,0)):INDEX(Data!$A:$A,INDEX(Data!$D:$D,MATCH(B2,Data!$B:$B,0))),A2)), 0) - 1)
```

*formula may contain a few errors, but concept should work*

**MORE FLEXIBLE MATCHING**
Excel offers some advanced fuzzy comparison functionality - which you can get in different ways depending on your version number. If you have an Excel 2016 or older, google "Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel". I also suggest you watch a few random training videos for it on youtube. It will most definitely match say JONG DE and DE JONG. If you have Office 365, fuzzy compare has been built into Power Query. Again have a look at youtube (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s5KcTNy4rs). The latter option is really powerful and I guess you could generate your required data in a few clicks without any formulas.

**UNABLE TO SORT?**

Easy answer: save the workbook on google drive and open/convert it to Google Sheets and sort there, or if its a once off thing, ask a friend to do it on a more powerful PC. You should also File > Save as > Browse > Save as type > "Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb). This might/should reduce memory requirements, at least for auto-saving and saving/loading times.

**BUT MY FORMULAS!**

Last option, which kind-of solves both the sort and fuzzy search. You can build your own semi-fuzzy compare by extracting say the two or more longest words from the name field and concatenate that separately with the DOB (e.g. "01-01-1964 JONG"). First you make say up to 4 helper columns and extract four keywords from the name column using space, dash and comma as separators. Without sorting, you could now do a unique MATCH based on each of the concatenated values. The number of matches would give you a confidence level to pair with the column C number.

If you can sort (still preferable), you'd only have to do the keyword splitting on the smaller one of the two tables. And no need to do the concatenation with the DOB. You find the list of DOB as above, and then SEARCH the whole name string with each keyword.

Comment: Thanks Mobus for the quick reply. I never thought of solving my problem without VBA. Just tried it out but still have some issues. In my real file there are almost 220k rows and my computer has memory issues if I try to sort the data. In the test file with just a few rows your formula works well on my laptop. Unfortunately it does not consider the different ways to write a surname and only returns the required value if the surname is a perfect match. Do you know a way to alter the formula if I want to have a value returned even with a partial match? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way I wrote it, the comparison will take "BERG", "DEUR", "JONG DE" in DATA and search for it anywhere inside a string. So it would find "BERG" in say "BERG - STEVENS". But sadly "JONG DE" and "DE JONG" is difficult. That being said, I'll suggest some ways to deal with the sorting and matching problems, editing my existing solution.

Comment: Thanks, will probably have less issues with sorting at work. Have to see if I can erase the insertions from both sheets and see if matching will go better than.

Comment: Updated solution.